# TestNG: Is the possible to give thread-count at class level in TestNG

Tags: multithreading, selenium, testng

I have a scenarios where I have multiple module and each module has multiple classes and each class has multiple methods.
Wondering If I can provide thread-count at class level to run methods in a particular class in parallel to save execution time.

```
<suite thread-count="1" name="Parallel Execution Suite" parallel="tests">
  <test thread-count="1" name="Test1" parallel="classes">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
    <classes>
     <class thread-count="2" name="testCases.testclass1.java"  parallel="methods" />
     <class thread-count="2" name="testCases.testclass2.java"  parallel="methods" />
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test1 -->
</suite> <!-- Parallel Execution Suite -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`parallel` and `thread-count` attributes can not be used at the `class`  element.
You can define the parallel mode at `suite` and `test` elements. However, if you ultimately want to execute each method in a separate thread, simply use parallel attribute at suite level with `parallel="methods"`

For more information, refer: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Krishna for comments. I am aware of threads=method at suite & Test level. As per latest requirement looking that if I can give a thread-count to class so all methods in that class can run in parallel on those number of threads. I want to give different number of threads to each class based on number of methods that class has.